# Как сделать рандом, чтобы чем больше цифра, тем меньше шанс?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

мне нужно сделать так чтобы был типо рандом но не рандом, цифры могут быть любыми, просто необходимо то чтобы чем больше цифра , тем меньше шанс на ее выпадение.

Comment: Весь вопрос в том, какое именно распределение вас интересует. Просто "чтоб было меньше" - имеются бесконечно много вариантов...

Comment: Чем больше, тем меньше шанс.

Comment: Меньше - это и линейно, и экспоненциально, и ограниченно, и неограниченно, и целые числа, и вещественные... При вашем ТЗ остается только развести руками и сказать "ХЗ..."

Comment: @GLhF, возьми геометрическое распределение, например...

Answer (score 5):

Раз вы не ставите задачу точно - вот один из вариантов - для вещественных положительных чисел, экспоненциальное распределение [image: введите сюда описание изображения] с параметром 0.1:

```
mt19937 gen(random_device{}());
exponential_distribution<> d(0.1);

for(int n=0; n<100; ++n)
    cout << d(gen) << endl;
```

[Тут](https://ideone.com/GKRpk7) можете сами посмотреть, как часто встречаются числа побольше и поменьше...

Таких распределений - "*при больших шансов поменьше*" - огромное количество... мощность континуума... Поэтому для *точного* ответа нужен точный вопрос.

*Без точного ТЗ результат - ХЗ*...

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое - взять результат ГСЧ (от 0 до 1) и возвести в степень (например, в квадрат). Так, из равномерного распределения, вы получите неравномерное, в том же диапазоне от 0 до 1, с преобладанием меньших чисел.

Для более точного ответа, надо знать/указать желаемое распределение и диапазон чисел.